# What does selenium WebDriverExeption status code means?

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, geckodriver

i try to run selenium on firefox using python and ubuntu 20.04 and keep getting this error

```
  File "tst3.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 175, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 101, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 113, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64
```

what does "Status code 64" mean ?

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?

Comment: @Yash, nope, i didn't find meaning exactly of this status code, but i found way to make selenium work for me through binary path

Comment: Ohh cool.. Even I tried by changing the version of geckodriver and it worked!